# Is it secure to send the user UID to firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore collection and every user has one document. The document name is equal to the user UID.

I write to these documents with a firebase function. So I pass the user UID to this firebase cloud function so the function can write to the database (this is just a very simple write so I won't show it here).

Here is the function call in my js file:

```
const saveAllTimeData = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('saveAllTimeData');
saveAllTimeData({ data: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid })
```

But I am not very sure if this is safe.

Can't just someone change the `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` part before the execution? And f.e. put in another uid to change documents he shouldn't be able to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's UID is safe to share as a UID acts like a fingerprint to differentiate and identify a user from another. these do not in any way give permission or power over that user, it is simply a random set of characters that is unique.

With the Admin SDK, you are also able to create these UID's per design, allowing you to have a custom UID that may represent their username if so desired.

Since you are also using a httpsCallable cloud function, this includes a value called *context*, which uses the JWT token from the auth module. the JWT token is decodable to the user and should not be shared. however, the method httpsCallable secures it through the HTTPS tunnel making it secure from most hijacking.

in your function, you should notice the context variable

```js
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

For onCall, context contains a property called `auth` of which contains the decoded JWT values

```js
// Message text passed from the client.
const text = data.text;
// Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
const uid = context.auth.uid;
const name = context.auth.token.name || null;
const picture = context.auth.token.picture || null;
const email = context.auth.token.email || null;
```

references

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#oncall
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: But I heard, that you can change js before execution. Can't someone just rewrite this function to: const saveAllTimeData = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('saveAllTimeData');
saveAllTimeData({ data: "a uid of another user" })

Comment: it is possible to modify all requests, but the main takeaway is that the uid isn't and shouldn't be used to define user permissions, only identify. instead, you should look at the JWT that is mentioned in my post. I will update with references soon

Comment: inside your cloud function, you would check the users permissions, and validate their requests. the JWT token expires every 1 hour making it unlikely for the request to be hijacked and repeated. you can also expire the JWT to ensure all requested JWT's are unique but that is outside of the scope of this question

Comment: So instead of passing the uid as an argument I can just access it with context.auth.uid and so it is ensured that the user writes the data to his own document?

Comment: Correct. Also, if you are writing data to a document, why not use a combination of rules and the database modules?